# Trapping water in a 2D matrix suspended in space

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, heap

Given an m x n matrix of positive integers representing the height of each unit cell in a 2D elevation map suspended in space, compute the volume of water it is able to trap after unlimited supply of water from top . 0 represents a leakage ( matrix is suspended in space )
Note:

Both m and n are less than 110. The height of each unit cell is greater than 0 and is less than 20,000. have a list of lists where `0` in the sublists represents a leakage. 
Below are  described example :

```
[[3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3],
[3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3],
[3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3]]
ans = 4
```

We can only fill 4 units of water in this case. That's is 2 units in both 1's  in 5th column, because if more than 2 units is filled it would overflow. while the water in the left valley that is left of columns 0 to 3 would leak through 0.

Eg 2

```
 [[1,4,3,1,3,2],
  [3,2,1,3,2,4],
  [2,3,3,2,3,1]]
```

Ans = 4
How to proceed?
Below is the logic of treating 0 as on the ground. I want to modify this to the case of 0 representing leakage/drainage.

```
def trapRainWater(self, heightMap):
    """
    :type heightMap: List[List[int]]
    :rtype: int
    """
    m = len(heightMap)
    if not m:
        return 0
    n = len(heightMap[0])
    if not n:
        return 0

    is_visited = [[False for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(m)]

    heap = []
    for i in xrange(m):
        heappush(heap, [heightMap[i][0], i, 0])
        is_visited[i][0] = True
        heappush(heap, [heightMap[i][n-1], i, n-1])
        is_visited[i][n-1] = True
    for j in xrange(n):
        heappush(heap, [heightMap[0][j], 0, j])
        is_visited[0][j] = True
        heappush(heap, [heightMap[m-1][j], m-1, j])
        is_visited[m-1][j] = True

    trap = 0
    while heap:
        height, i, j = heappop(heap)
        for (dx, dy) in [(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]:
            x, y = i+dx, j+dy
            if 0 <= x < m and 0 <= y < n and not is_visited[x][y]:
                trap += max(0, height - heightMap[x][y])
                heappush(heap, [max(height, heightMap[x][y]), x, y])
                is_visited[x][y] = True

    return trap
```

Comment: Just an idea: in your `while` loop, when you analyze the 4 adjacent "tiles" to the currently analyzed "tile", if you find an elevation of  `0`  for any of those tiles, go to the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: @Eldy yeah! I have tried it but it doesnt stop the tiles adjacent to 0 from filling water, because it doesnt know that'll spill out